# Is it Possible to globally set the java hs_err log Location?

Tags: command-line, configuration, java

I know when executing a jar using the command line option

```
-XX:ErrorFile=[location]
```

allows you to change where the hs_err log files are placed.

I am wondering: is there is a place I can globally define this ErrorFile location and be able to omit it from execution commands?

Answer (score 1):

Java runtimes honor environment variables, you could set them in system startup files.

Oracle Java uses [`_JAVA_OPTIONS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677346/java-system-environment-variable), IBM Java uses [`IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224215).